# inout String acceptable in AIDL

Tags: android, aidl, android-binder

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) states that

> all non-primitive parameters require a directional tag indicating which way the data goes; and
>
> primitives are in by default, and cannot be otherwise.

Then they proceed with giving an example where a `String` is missing the directional tag. Can a `String` be `out` or `inout` in Android AIDL?

Since strings are immutable I'd have to do an assignment on the method handling the call in order to change the string, something like `myString = "hello to you too";`. I know that in a regular method this argument `myString` would remain unchanged at the caller side. Is that behavior applied here?

Comment: What's your question actually?

Comment: @pskink In other words, can a string be used to retrieve a value from the callee using the out argument. Method signature example: `public boolean meth1(int n, inout Car car, out String s);`.

Comment: No, as String can be only 'in'

Comment: Any assignment to an argument, done inside the method handling the call, will be lost like it usually is in Java?

Comment: Yes, this is how it works